# regard continuous colons as part of a word

Tags: keyword

I want to regard continuous colons as part of a word.
How can I configure the `iskeyword` option?

For example,

- in `::hoge`, the whole thing is a word
- in `:hoge`, `:` is a word, and `hoge` is also a word
- in `fuga:hoge`, `fuga` is a word, `:` is also a word, and `hoge` is also a word
- in `fuga::hoge`, the whole thing is a word
- in `hoge:::`, the whole thing is a word

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! I’m not sure iskeyword can do what you’re hoping to accomplish. Perhaps someone can find a clever mapping of w/W/b/B/e/E/ge/gE, but as you might guess it could be complex/difficult to maintain.